# Software or web app for creating dependency graph

Tags: software-recommendation, diagram

I need to create dependency graph diagram for non-technical purpose - concept brainstorming. Tree diagram such as mind map doesn't meet my needs. Any software or web app you would recommend? Below are my needs:

**Node**

- stereotype/node type
- (must have) unique name
- support at least 200 nodes per diagram.

**Connection between nodes**

- optional label
- (must have) each node may have > 1 incoming and outgoing connections
- for multiple connections out of a given node, they can be grouped by OR or AND (or mixed of both)
- (bonus) for connections grouped by OR, they can be assigned with weightage number.

**User interface**

- (must have) create diagram through GUI rather than scripting (doesn't have to be drag and drop, perhaps dialog is even better than drag and drop for complex diagram).
- (must have) auto-align to improve readability of diagram.
- subgraph can be collapsed/expanded.

(Bonus) A bit greedy for diagramming, able to **answer query** such as:

- which are the nodes having high number of incoming/outgoing direct connections?
- which are the nodes having high number of upstream/downstream dependencies?

--- updated 2/29

Highlighted must have functionality.

Comment: Have you tried [yEd Graph Editor](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use almost any vector image editor to make such graphs.  Inkscape (free and Open Source), Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer, CorelDraw, etc, etc.  Or if these are too complex, perhaps something simpler such as LibreOffice's Draw application would suffice.

The only thing I can see which probably couldn't be achieved using vector image editors is the interactivity you want. These are something that would probably require coding on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand all your requirements. In particular, I don't understand the interactive features.
However, you might want to check out the "yEd" graph editor (https://www.yworks.com/products/yed).

- Java-based, i.e. it runs everywhere as long as there is a Java Runtime environment.
- Comes with a variety of standard shapes, ready to use, but you can add your own ones based on SVG.
- Easy to align nodes one to the other because it dynamically shows auxiliary lines, comparable to what Adobe Illustrator does.
- Easily enter a text-label to the currently selected node (or to a connection line) just by hitting [F2].
- Select a node and hit the [F6] key to open a detailed Properties dialog.
- One of the properties in this dialog is to assign a URL to the node.
- Connect two nodes just by dragging the mouse-pointer from the source node to the target node. By default, this connects the two node-centers, but it is possible to select the connection line (afterwards) and edit it. No restrictions of the number of connecting lines.
- The GUI has several sub-panels, that e.g. do some "book-keeping" of existing connections, so that you can e.g. browse through a tabular list of node-labels.
- It has a "Group" feature, grouped nodes are framed into a special group-node that can be minimized at any time, to win some more space/better overview of the canvas.
- Drawings can be exported to SVG. Optionally, the exported SVG can have all the URLs as SVG-hyperlinks.